# Using Generic Repository with TEntity in Unity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unity-container, repository-pattern

I am learning how to use the Unity Framework for Dependency Injection in asp.net MVC 5 projects.

In general, I would set up a mapping for my repositories like this:

```
public static void RegisterComponents()
{
    var container = new UnityContainer();

    // e.g. container.RegisterType<ITestService, TestService>();
    container.RegisterType<IModelRepository, ModelRepository>();

    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
}
```

Is it possible to do this with a generic Repository which looks like this:

```
 public class GenericRepository<TEntity> 
       : IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
 { /* ... */ }
```

Out of instinct I would set up and register this like this:

```
container.RegisterType<IGenericRepository<TEntity>, GenericRepository<TEntity>>();
```

which does not work.

Do I need to register a Generic Repository for every model type like this?

```
container.RegisterType<IGenericRepository<Model1>, GenericRepository<Model1>>();
container.RegisterType<IGenericRepository<Model2>, GenericRepository<Model2>>();
container.RegisterType<IGenericRepository<Model3>, GenericRepository<Model3>>();
...
container.RegisterType<IGenericRepository<Model_N>, GenericRepository<Model_N>>();
```

Or is there a way to inject this repository once for all model classes and controllers?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can register the generic types for any TEntity this way:

```
container.RegisterType(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>));
```

See the msdn on [Unity 2.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660936(v=pandp.20).aspx) or [Unity 3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463(v=pandp.30).aspx) (Registering Open Generics section)

Comment: The wall of text, made me miss this part - or lead to me not understanding it. Thank you a lot. This works like a charm and saved me a lot of code.